# Session is not defined error Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I am trying to create an HTTP server with cookie, but while executing the code, it returns me error, saying that the session is not defined.

**My code (updated code) :**

```
   //Initializing the modules
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var queryParser = require('express-query-int');
var format = require('util').format;
var app = connect();
var app = express();
// setup middleware
app.use(queryParser());
app.use(cookieParser('this is my secret string'));
app.use(session({
secret: cookie_secret,
name: cookie_name,
store: sess, // connect-mongo session store
proxy: true,
resave: true, 
saveUninitialized: true
// Cookie Options
//maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hours
}));
// actually respond
app.use(function(req, res) {
for (var name in req.query) {
req.session[name] = req.query[name];
}
res.end(format(req.session) + '\n');
});
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

I saw in some documentations that using `connect-session` is not more good to use, now we use `express-session`, but how can I make that work ?

Now the error is in the `maxAge`, where points out that is an unexpected identifier, how can I correct that ?

Comment: Looks like you already answered your question... go look at the documentation for express-session: https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: I changed to express-session, but it says that maxAge is an unexpected identifier. How can I change that ?

Comment: Post your updated code